# How to use WL.SecurityUtils?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to save cipher binary files in iPhone and to use *WL.WL.SecurityUtils* of MFP V7.0 JavaScript Client-side.
Could you let me know how to use that? 
I have questions as follows.

Q1. Can I set the valeu like a sample `'salt: Math.random().toString()'` to Salt(WL.SecurityUtils.keygen parameter) ?

Q2. Could you let me know the return parameter stracture, names and others ?
    What I needed to use  at WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt?

WL.SecurityUtils.encrypt Returns:
    {Promise} Resolved when the operation succeeds, first parameter is an object which includes the cipher text.

Q3.What value can I set the parameter({string} options.iv - Required. Initialization Vector) of WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt ?
   When I use iPhone, can I set 'obj' to the parameter {string} options.src `- Required. Source ('obj' = iOS, 'java' = Android, 'js' = Web).`

```
 WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt Parameters:<br/>
    {object} options - Required. <br/>
    {string} options.key - Required. Key. <br/>
    {string} options.ct - Required. Cipher Text. <br/>
    {string} options.iv - Required. Initialization Vector. <br/>
    {string} options.src - Required. Source ('obj' = iOS, 'java' = Android, 'js' = Web). <br/>
    {number} options.v - Required. Version. <br/>
```

Q4. Is it OK that I store key and parameters of *WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt* ( iv, src and v ) to JSONStore ?

JSONStore security utilities

```
[http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_sec_utils_overview.html?lang=en]
```

Answer (score 0):

Q1. Can I set the value like a sample `salt: Math.random().toString()` to Salt(WL.SecurityUtils.keygen parameter)

A1. I don't really understand your question here but if you asking how to use WL.SecurityUtils.keygen you can do the following.

```
WL.SecurityUtils.keygen({
   password: 'hello world',
   salt : '12345',
   iteration : 300
})
```

Q2. Could you let me know the return parameter stracture, names and others ? What I needed to use at WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt?

A2. Assuming that you are using decrypt in conjunction with encrypt.

```
var key = 'this is a secret key';
var src = 'js';
WL.SecurityUtils.encrypt({
    key : key,
    text : 'secret text'
})
   .then(function (res){
     return WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt({
        key : key,
        ct : res.ct,
        iv : res.iv,
        src : src,
        v   : res.v,
   });
});

 .then(function (res) {
    console.log("Decrypted Text " + res);
})
.fail(function (err) {
   console.log("There was a problem : " + JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Q3. What value can I set the parameter({string} options.iv - Required. Initialization Vector) of WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt ? When I use iPhone, can I set 'obj' to the parameter {string} options.src - Required. Source ('obj' = iOS, 'java' = Android, 'js' = Web).

A3. The value for options.iv is generated as a response from encrypt.So it is recommended to use both encrypt and decrypt. Src can have the following values : 'java', 'objc', and 'js'. Where java is for Android, objc is for iOS and js is for Web.

Q4. Is it OK that I store key and parameters of WL.SecurityUtils.decrypt ( iv, src and v ) to JSONStore ?

A4. I would say this would be permitted only if your JSONStore is encrypted because you are storing all of your keys for your encrypted resource.

I hope this answers your questions.